# Rules - show information after certain time

Tags: 7, rules

I'm wondering how can I achieve this.
I have built a page, on which the content of certain type was being unpublished after 2 weeks. I created rule for that (component + component schedule) and it worked without problem.

But now I have to change the behavior - instead of old content being just "removed from sight of users", it has to remain visible but display a message. Something in the line of "this content has expired, but you can check for available offers on the main page".

I thought that setting the rule and picking up the "display message on site" could be what I'm looking for, but seems like I was wrong. No idea if I can do it in Views (how to link specific Rule to it?), so I'm looking for help.

Any ideas how to achieve that message displaying to users after certain time has passed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to achieve it with rules, you can do it with the following steps:

1. Add new rule
2. React on event: Content is viewed (under Node section)
3. Add new condition: Data comparison
4. Data to compare: `node:created`
5. Operator: 'is lower than'
6. Data value: Switch to the direct input mode and put '-2 weeks', or '-14 days'
7. Add new action: 'Show a message on the site' (under System section)
8. Put your message in as value, and select the type of the message. E.g. 'Status'

Comment: Oh, I totally didn't think about making it that way. Thanks, I will try it!